# Find the largest real number r such that r[r] = 2019{r}

Tags: contest-math

[r] denotes the greatest integer less than or equal to r

{r} denotes the fractional part of r

This problem is tripping me up. Obviously r has to be some sort of decimal, or else the fractional part of it would be 0. The fact that [r] is the floor of r also makes this confusing for me. Overall, this problem just feels *hard* to work with.

edit: got it! thank you guys!

Comment: Write $r = n+\alpha$ for $\alpha \in [0,1)$. Then $(n+\alpha)n = 2019 \alpha \implies \alpha = \frac{n^2}{2019-n}$. Having $\alpha \ge 0$ and $\alpha < 1$ corresponds to $n < 2019$ and $2019-n < n^2$. Now solve the quadratic.

Comment: Whenever you have an equation that involves fractional and integer parts, if you don't have any better ideas you should write $r$ as mathworker21 suggests and see where that leads.  Often you can get rid of the fractional parts and floors and get to a normal equation.

Comment: The FAQ encourages you to write up your own question if you figure it out.  After a couple days you can accept the answer as well.  That way it doesn't stay unanswered.